# View() for S4 class extending data.frame

Tags: r, r-s4

Im trying to define a S4 class extending `data.frame` which behaves just like a `data.frame` but holds some additional information in the slot `info`. This works fine for almost all functions I would use on a `data.frame` but fails with `View()`, because when I use `View()` on my class, it doesn't show the tabular form you see when calling it with a `data.frame` but rather the form you usually see when calling `View()` on a list.

Here is what I've tried:

```
#Define class
setOldClass("data.frame")
setClass(
  "myDF",
  contains= "data.frame",
  slots = c(info = "character")
)

#Set method for as.data.frame
setMethod(
  "as.data.frame",
  signature = "myDF",
  function(x, ...){
    S3Part(x, strictS3 = T)
  }
)

#create instance
d <- new("myDF", data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10), info="someInfo")

#This doesn't show the tabular structure but looks like calling View() on a list
View(d)

#What I want it to look like
View(as.data.frame(d))
```

The documentation of `View()` states "Object x is coerced (if possible) to a data frame", which is why I implemented the method for `as.data.frame()`, hoping this would fix the problem.

I'd be grateful for any input on what I've gotten wrong here.

Edit: I've added screenshots of how it looks under both of the RStudio versions I mentioned in the answer.

[image: View(d) under RStudio 1.3.1093]

[image: View(d) under RStudio 1.4.1106]

Comment: Could you please show an screenshot of how you like it vs how it is being shown?

Comment: I  put the screenshots in the post. As mentioned in the answer down below however, this seemed to be caused by the outdated RStudio version I was using and could be fixed by updating RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself: Turns out this behaviour seemed to depend on the RStudio version I used. After updating from RStudio version 1.3.1093 to 1.4.1106, `View(d)` and `View(as.data.frame(d))` show the same results.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the difference between the versions are, and the relevant change that made it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I searched the release notes but couldn't find anything that I thought could explain the change in behaviour.